# Does an Outsider (Native) player character also get all the Bestiary Outsider features?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, balance

This might be a dumb question, but I can't seem to find a solid answer for it anywhere on Google, and I can't help but feel like it makes the Aasimar I'm making stronger than I thought... When a PC is playing an Outsider (Native), do they gain the [Bestiary Outsider Features and Traits?](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/) Or is this limited to non-PCs? Does Native change any of that besides what the bestiary says specifically that it changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Aasimar PC gets all the traits of a native outsider (like Darkvision).

however, an Aasimar does not have racial hit die. Thus it won't get the 'Features' of the outsider 'class'.

Instead the Aasimar gains class lvs just like a human would. thus a lv 1 wizard Aasimar would have 0 BAB and 1d6HD. Not 1 BAB and 1d10HD.

Comment: *"weapon proficiencies"*, no they do not. [Source](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qb14&page=3?Zero-HD-Native-Outsiders-and-Weapon#130).

Comment: @ShadowKras wow :O didn't know that, ill remove it from my anwser, guess the weapon proficiencies are a part of the "outsider class" then

Answer (score 6):

If you take a look at the Playable Races section in [Creature Types & Subtypes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types) it mentions:

> The second difference is that all of these race types are 0-Hit Dice creatures, which means that their Hit Dice, base attack bonus, saving throw progression, skill points, class skills, and weapon and armor proficiencies are based on the class levels each member of a race takes.

The other interesting pieces on your linked page seem to be dealt with specifically on the Aasimar race page (such as getting dark vision) or not apply to the native subtype.

Answer (score 2):

### No, they don't.

You do not gain any of the [outsider creature traits](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/), such as:

- Proficiency with all simply and martial weapons;
- Racial hit dice (d10);
- Base attack bonus equal to hit dice.;
- Reflex and Will good saving throws;
- Skill points equal to 6+int modifier;

You gain the listed traits on the [Aasimar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-aasimar/) race. Other than their *type*, they don't gain any of the outsider traits. *Darkvision*, which is common between the two, is listed as a racial trait for Aasimars, which would be a duplicate if we were supposed to gain outsider traits.

> (Type: Aasimars are outsiders with the native subtype.

If we check the [Playable Races](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races#TOC-Playable-Races) (which was printed on the bestiary), characters from races with 0-HD do not gain several traits from the creature type, and as such, they are based on the character class taken:

> The second difference is that all of these race types are 0-Hit Dice creatures, which means that their **Hit Dice**, **base attack bonus**, **saving throw progression**, **skill points**, **class skills**, and **weapon and armor proficiencies** are based on the class levels each member of a race takes.

This ruling was revised to be clearer between the publishing of the *Bestiary* and *Advanced Players Guide* ([Source](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qb14&page=3?Zero-HD-Native-Outsiders-and-Weapon#130)), and later corrected on the next printings of the *Bestiary*.