# Shapechanger subtype & Free Shield Proficiency

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The [shapechanger subtype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/#TOC-Shapechanger-Subtype), lists the following ability;

> A shapechanger is proficient with shields if it is proficient with any type of armor.

Would this mean that, for example, a [Rogue](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/#TOC-Weapon-and-Armor-Proficiency) [skinwalker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/more-races/standard-races-1-10-rp/skinwalkers-10-rp/) PC (which have the shapechanger subtype), would gain Shield Proficiency for free? — Or is there some rule that prevents PCs from gaining abilities from subtypes?

(Rogues have light armour proficiency, but not shield proficiency)

Comment: [Closely related.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102797/8610)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You do not gain the subtype's proficiencies

As explained on [Playable Races](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races#TOC-Playable-Races):

> **Playable Races**
>
> When discussing or considering a playable race’s type, it’s type is similar to the corresponding creature type, with a few important differences.
>
> - The first difference is that each race type assumes members of the race are roughly humanoid in shape and have two arms, two legs, a torso, and a head. This is important so that a race can take advantage of all the various magic item slots available to characters and can utilize the standard weapon and armor options.
> - The second difference is that all of these race types are 0-Hit Dice creatures, which means that their Hit Dice, base attack bonus, saving throw progression, skill points, class skills, and **weapon and armor proficiencies are based on the class levels each member of a race takes**.

Here, the author is talking about a **race's type** as a [creature type](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/) of the character's race (monstrous humanoid, outsider, dragon, etc) and how they decided that 0-HD races should gain some of their class-related abilities (saves, skills, proficiencies, etc) from their class instead of gaining it from their racial HD.

This caused confusion when the *core rulebook* and *bestiary* were published because of aasimars, which are outsiders with [native subtype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/#TOC-Native-Subtype), were the only non-humanoid playable race, as [outsiders](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/#TOC-Outsider) do gain proficiencies, skill ranks per HD and several class skills. But later this was clarified on the *Advanced Race Guide* with the text I quoted, and those 0-HD races do not gain proficiencies if they have a character class.

Comment: I tried composing a similar answer but got hung up on describing the difference between the term *race* and (OMG, *Pathfinder*, seriously, *Why!? Are synonyms* so *hard!?*) the term *race type*. I was really kind of hoping your (seemingly inevitable! `;-)`) answer would articulate the difference, both for the asker and me.

Comment: I am not sure the term *race type* has any different meaning other than *races of non-humanoid types*.

Comment: See, that's the thing: The answer lets the quotation speak for itself, yet it doesn't tell the whole story. It says "The… difference is that…," yet the answer doesn't explain what the quotation is differentiating between, which is, I think, kind of important for understanding this issue.

Comment: So does this also apply to monsters/npcs who are playable races and have class levels?

Comment: If they have no racial hit dice, yes. Doesn't apply to an ogre barbarian or succubus bard, for example.